# Generate random variables without cholesky decomposition

Tags: probability, matrices, probability-theory

How would you generate *n* standard normal random variables with $n\times n$ correlation matrix $R = (r_{ij} )$
where
$r_{ij}$ is

- $1$ if $i = j$
- $\rho$ if $i \neq j$,

with $\rho \geq 0$ **without using Cholesky decomposition**.

Comment: You had asked esentially the same question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1799866/generaling-dependent-random-variables except for the bit "without Cholesky". Don't do that, edit your own question. Furthermore, don't use this as a "do my homework for me" site. Make you own effort, show it to us, and answer the comments/questions of the people who try to help you.

Comment: @leonbloy I apologize for the wrong impression but these questions are final exam prep questions, not homework. My professor's notes aren't very clear on the subject and I just needed to be pointed in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously we need $\rho \le 1$.

Take a random vector $\mathbf{X}\sim \mathcal{N}(0,I_{n\times n})$ and a real RV $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1), Z \perp \mathbf{X}.$

Then it is easy to check that $\sqrt{\rho}\cdot Z \cdot \mathbf{1}_{n\times 1}+ \sqrt{1-\rho}\cdot \mathbf{X}$ has the distribution you want.

Comment: +1. What would you do with $\rho \lt 0$?

Comment: That isn't a valid covariance matrix, since it's not positive definite.

Comment: @enthdegree There is a tiny window for negative $\rho$. The proposed correlation matrix will be positive definite iff $\rho>-\frac1{n-1}$. See e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1790747/215011

Comment: Wow, my linear algebra intuition is fouled up! I suppose for negative $\rho$ you can generate RVs $Z_k$ for $k=1,\dots,n$, all independent and $\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ then form a random vector ${\mathbf X}$ with components: $$X_k=Z_k \cdot \sqrt{1-(n-1)\cdot \alpha } - \sum_{m\neq k} \sqrt{\alpha} \cdot Z_m,$$ where $\alpha$ is the solution to: $$\sqrt{\alpha}\cdot \sqrt{1-(n-1)\cdot \alpha }=\|\rho\|$$

Answer (score 0):

The facts about the correlation matrix tell us that it has ones on the diagonal and the specified correlation on the non-diagonals.

You can generate 3 i.i.d standard normal variables ($X,Y,Z$).

Define 3 new R.Vs ($U,V,W$) as

$U= aX + bY + bZ$

$V= bX + aY + bZ$

$W=bX+bY+aZ$

where $(a,b)$ solves $a^2 +2b^2 = 1$ and $2ab + b^2 = p$